# Pass varible with slash into nginx

Tags: nginx, url, parameters, special-characters, slash

nginx rewiting resolve slash in variable.
How to do with nginx to pass a content parameter a slash (/) ?
ex: /1524/Ri/Hr/p2 (Ri/Hr is the parameter)

So THX

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? What is the use case? nginx will normalize the request URI before the internal URI processing mechanism will take its place, even if you make your request as `http://example.com/1524/Ri%2FHr/p2` during the normalization it will become the `/1524/Ri/Hr/p2`. However depending on the use case some kind of workaround can (or cannot) be possible.

Comment: my url is formatted as following http://example.com/1524/Ri%2FHr/p2
In my url rewriting I have 3 parameters, but when url is processed it looks for 4 parameters.

rewrite ^/([0-9]*)/([^?]*)/p([0-9]*)/?$ /index.php?nid=$1&label=$2&page=$3 last;

Comment: What is your backend exactly is? Is it some kind of custom own-written PHP app or something more common?

Comment: Yes custom own-written PHP app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your PHP backend, if it isn't something that relies no the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable only (making any kind of rewrite rules senseless, it is the `REQUEST_URI` that should be tweaked instead in that case), you can try to use the non-normalized [`$request_uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) variable instead:

```
if ($request_uri ~ /(?<nid>\d+)/(?<label>[^/]+)/p(?<page>\d+)/?(?:\?|$)) {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?nid=$nid&label=$label&page=$page last;
}
```

The named captures usage instead of numbered ones is essential here since all the numbered captures and corresponding variables will be overwritten by the `rewrite` directive itself during the regex matching upon the `^` pattern.